# how to pass static value through url in blade file?

Tags: laravel

> I want to send static value through my url from my blade file .But this not working.can you give me the solution

```
> 
> <a href="{{URL::to('/user-login')?rfq=1 }}">This is link</a>
```

Comment: what are trying to do, what is not exactly working?? be more specific.

Comment: i want to set this link in my mailbody which is basically a blade .bt when i just write <a href="">this is link<a>   the mail  sent  but if i write <a href="{{URL::to('/user-login')?rfq=1 }}">This is link</a> this time mail does not send

Comment: when i click its redirect me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but i wanted http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-login?rfq=1@krik Bread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error you can fix by

```php
<a href="{{ URL::to('/user-login').'?rfq=1' }}">This is link</a>
```

here `?rfq=1` this will come under `''` this tag as it is string

---

as your router is defined as this

```php
Route::get('/user-login/{email}/{password}', 'UserController@user_login')->name('users.user_login');
```

you should use route name and pass the data like this

```php
<a href="{{ route('users.user_login',['email'=>'example@mail.com','password'=> '1234' ]) }}">This is link</a>
```

then if you need to pass you can use like this

```php
<a href="{{ route('users.user_login',['email'=>'example@mail.com','password'=> '1234','rfq'=>1]) }}">This is link</a>
```

this will generate url like `localhost:8000/user-login/example@mail.com/1234?rfq=1"`
ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route

Comment: when i click its redirect me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but i wanted http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-login?rfq=1

Comment: this code generate `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-login?rfq=1` this url but if it redirect to that url then you must be missing somthing

Comment: Route::get('/user-login/{email}/{password}', 'UserController@user_login')->name('users.user_login'); this is my route .can you help me to solve this issue

Comment: @RabbiMahmud check my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using {} in your route(route parameter method)  then no need to have '?' in  your URL. If you need 127.0.0.1:8000/user-login?rfq=1 as your URL then create route without route parameters as
Route::get('/user-login,'UserController@user_login')->name('users.user_login');